# What is difference between $\{(x,y): x< 2 \implies y >2\}$ and $\{(x,y): y > 2 \implies x <2\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

What is difference between $\{(x,y): x< 2  \implies y >2\}$ and $\{(x,y):  y > 2 \implies x <2\}$?

Let $S_1 = \{(x,y): x< 2  \implies y >2\}$, and $S_2 = \{(x,y):  y > 2 \implies x <2\}$. So $(1,3), (1,4),$ and $(1.5, 2.1)$, they are all in $S_1$ and in my opinion, it seem like they are also in $S_2$. I know that the set conditions in $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not equivalent. Also my professor said $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not the same sets. If I try to write $S_2$ in this way: $S_2 = \{(x,y): y \le 2 \implies x \ge 2\}$, will that work?

Comment: $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \lor B$. This could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, you must remember that an implication is true if the antecedant and consequent are both true, *xor* the antecedant is false.   You've examined only elements that were in the former (the intersection), neglecting those in the later (the difference).

$\{(x,y): x<2\to y>2\} = \{(x,y): x<2\wedge y>2\}\cup\{(x,y): x\geq 2\}\\
\{(x,y): y>2\to x<2\} = \{(x,y): x<2\wedge y>2\}\cup\underbrace{\{(x,y): y\leq 2\}}$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have

$$S_1=$$
$$[2,+\infty)\times\Bbb R\cup (-\infty,2)\times(2,+\infty) $$
and

$$S_2=$$
$$\Bbb R\times(-\infty,2]\cup(-\infty,2)\times(2,+\infty) .$$

it is clear that $S_1\ne S_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just one of an infinite number of examples:

[image: region examples]

Answer (score 0):

Letting $P(x)$ be $x<2$, and $Q(y)$ being $y>2$, we have that

$$S_1=\{(x,y):P(x)\implies Q(y)\}\ \text{and}\ S_2=\{(x,y):Q(y)\implies P(x)\}.$$
Note that the condition required of $(x,y)$ to be in $S_2$ is the converse of the condition required by $S_1$. So to show $S_1$ and $S_2$ are different, construct a truth table with $P$, $Q$, $P\implies Q$, $Q\implies P$, and identify the rows where the implications have different truth values. Then for any of the rows, find some $(x,y)$ such that $P$ and $Q$ have the truth values given in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\,\big(x \lt 2  \implies y \gt 2\big)$ $\iff \big(\lnot(x \lt 2) \lor (y \gt 2)\big)\,$, so $\,S_1=\{(x,y) : x \ge 2 \lor y \gt 2\}\,$. Similarly, $\,S_2 = \{(x,y) : x \lt 2 \lor y \le 2\}\,$.

It then becomes clear that, for example, $\,S_1 \setminus S_2 \ne \emptyset\,$, so the two sets are not identical:

$$
\begin{align}
S_1 \setminus S_2 &= \{(x,y) : \big(x \ge 2 \lor y \gt 2\big) \land \lnot\big(x \lt 2 \lor y \le 2\big)\} \\
 &=\{(x,y) : \big(x \ge 2 \lor y \gt 2\big) \land (x\ge2)\land(y \gt 2)\} \\
 &=\{(x,y):(x\ge2)\land(y \gt 2)\}
\end{align}
$$